# ajax recive variable value from php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Through ajax I ask for a php page which will get some information from database. When data are processed I echo them to some tag and through JS I target those tags and get their content. This is the only way how I can pass data between php and JS but I feel it's not quite right. Whats the best way to get value of php variable:

```
$var1 = 24515875;
```

into JS variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the following suggestion is too complex, but:
you could use jQuery Ajax Get for requesting JSON data from PHP.
This is good for passing arrays, like results sets from a database to the client-side.

On PHP side you would do a simple:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($myData);
?>
```

On JS side you would access this with:

```
$.getJSON( "getjsondata.php", function( data ) {
   alert(data);
   // do whatever, like appending to html element

   // next code section is the answer to your question from the comment:
   // how to iterate over the data result set?      

   // create new DomElement for insertion: here foreach row a new list item
   var items = [];
   $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
   });

   // then insert the list items into a UL and append that to the body
   $( "<ul/>", {
       "class": "my-new-list",
       html: items.join( "" )
   }).appendTo( "body" );  

   // to access the individual properties you would do
   alert(data.property);    

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: This is what I needed. Is there any way how can I assign those data from window Object directly? I have them in an array.

Comment: So, when you have your data on client-side (alert data shows up), then you would loop over the data array.. js code moved to my answer for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

When calling between PHP and JavaScript using AJAX, I suggest you always encode using JSON (Javascript Object Notation).

```
<?php
   // Set Header (Always should be first commands just in case of thrown errors)
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   $data = array(
      'message' => 'Hello World',
      'error' => false
   );
   echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

For the javascript, you can use XMLHttpRequest. I don't suggest using jQuery unless you need it for other aspects of your script.

```
function request(url,callback) {
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
         var json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
         if(typeof callback === "function") {
            callback(json);
         }
      }else{
         // Handle Error
      }
   }
   req.open("GET",url,true);
   req.send();
}

function callback_func(json) {
   // Function gets called when Ajax is finished
   console.dir(json);
}

request("ajax.php",callback_func);
```

Comment: Yes, this will work, too. But the question was tagged "javascript" and "jquery", so i believe Doge expects an answer including a jQuery solution.

Comment: A lot of new developers believe jQuery is the only solution, I was just giving my opinion about not having to need jQuery.

Comment: This can be a solution but like Jens said I was asking for jQuery solution. jQuery solution is much shorter and I don't have to worry about a lot of things.